# Netlify Mixed Content Error with GatsbyJS Plugin gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts

Tags: javascript, https, gatsby, webfonts, netlify

So I am using [gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts) in my project. I let it run through my localhost:8000 via pupeteer and create the `font-preload-cache.json`. However, now, when I deploy this to netlify I get the following error:

warning  / error

```
Insecure mixed content detected

Although you have enabled HTTPS on your site, we’ve detected some content that’s still being served over an HTTP connection. Learn more about mixed content.

In index.html:

Insecure link urls:
http://localhost:8000/static/roboto-condensed-latin-400-3ada4464a5d4d208c5e3591076c5138a.woff2
http://localhost:8000/static/roboto-latin-400-479970ffb74f2117317f9d24d9e317fe.woff2
http://localhost:8000/static/montserrat-latin-300-7c3daf12b706645b5d3710f863a4da04.woff2
http://localhost:8000/static/montserrat-latin-400-bc3aa95dca08f5fee5291e34959c27bc.woff2
http://localhost:8000/static/roboto-latin-300-ef7c6637c68f269a882e73bcb57a7f6a.woff2
```

First, I am wondering why there is no http**s** in front of these links? And then I'm also wondering whether they point to localhost? Surely this is false? Or is it not?